# Time countdown in an tooltip

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-tooltip

This is my countdown script :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>        
    function cronometru(timp_ramas) {
        Ore = Math.floor(timp_ramas / 3600);
        minute = Math.floor((timp_ramas - Ore * 3600) / 60);
        secunde = timp_ramas - minute * 60 - Ore * 3600;
        if (Ore < 10){ Ore = "0"+ Ore; }
        if (minute < 10){ minute = "0" + minute; }
        if (secunde < 10){ secunde = "0" + secunde; }
        if (timp_ramas > 0) {

            timp_ramas--;
            document.getElementById("timp").innerHTML = Ore + ':' + minute + ':' + secunde;

            setTimeout("cronometru("+timp_ramas+")", 1000);

        } else {
            document.getElementById("timp").innerHTML = "Focul s-a stins !";

        }
    }
```

```
$timp_ramas = $citeste['timp_ramas_pentru_foc'] - time(); // this is the function that retrives the actual time from an database.
```

I use this "wz_tooltip.js" for the tooltip events.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="wz_tooltip.js"></script>
```

When i try to put  to show my conuntdown in the tooltip the tooltip goes black and show only the message before or after the countdown position  ('Timp ramas :')

Example :

```
    if ($citeste["timp_ramas_pentru_foc"] > 0)
{

 echo "
<a onmouseover=

\"Tip('Timp ramas : <span id=timp></span> ')\"  
onmouseout=\"UnTip()\">

<img src='img/skiluri/fire_yes.png'/>  </a>

    ";
}
```

I found a way to make the code to work but the timer will be shown in 2 places in the same time. I want only to read it when i move the cursor on some picture / text and the tooltip apears.

Example of working code with 2 views in the same time :

```
      $timp_ramas = $citeste['timp_ramas_pentru_foc'] - time();
      ?>


   <script type='text/javascript'>        
    function cronometru(timp_ramas) {
        Ore = Math.floor(timp_ramas / 3600);
        minute = Math.floor((timp_ramas - Ore * 3600) / 60);
        secunde = timp_ramas - minute * 60 - Ore * 3600;
        if (Ore < 10){ Ore = "0"+ Ore; }
        if (minute < 10){ minute = "0" + minute; }
        if (secunde < 10){ secunde = "0" + secunde; }
        if (timp_ramas > 0) {

            timp_ramas--;
            document.getElementById("timp").innerHTML = Ore + ':' + minute + ':' + secunde;

            setTimeout("cronometru("+timp_ramas+")", 1000);

        } else {
            document.getElementById("timp").innerHTML = "Focul s-a stins !";

        }
    }
```

```
    <script src="js/meniu_dreapta/iconmenu.js"></script>
     <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tooltip/wz_tooltip.js"></script>

   <span id='timp'></span>  <?php echo "<script type='text/javascript'>cronometru(".$timp_ramas.")</script>";   ?>

<?php


    echo '
    <html>
    <ul id="myiconmenu" class="iconmenu"> ';

    if ($citeste["timp_ramas_pentru_foc"] > 0)
{

 echo "
<a onmouseover=

\"Tip('Timp ramas : <span id=timp></span> ')\"  
onmouseout=\"UnTip()\">

<img src='img/skiluri/fire_yes.png'/>  </a>

    ";
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something demonstrating all this..?

Comment: i can't provide a code in fiddle because the code is in 'preloading' screen for another file . i can provide the hole file instead here : http://www.fileshare.ro/e30600249 or here : http://fisierulmeu.ro/41PTXHSZEL7Q/inceputpagina2-php.html

Comment: does not matter anymore , i can't find a logical solution for this problem so in css i made something like " .hide-row { display:none; } " and the i altered in php to hide the row. Problem solved :) Thanks for the overlook